# Pentaho CDE - Export dashboard to pdf/excel format

Tags: export, pentaho, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf, pentaho-cde

I need to export my dashboard CDE (Pentaho 7.1) to pdf/excel format.
By default Pentaho seems do not export CDE dashboards, but googling a little bit on this I found some post with export just of table or graph of the dashboard.

Please can anyone help me?
I would like export entire dashboard to pdf/excel format.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently exporting entire dashboard feature is not available, you can only export specific component like tables or charts but it also having a different method.

We have handled this feature by writing a JavaScript, and used some plugins which allows to take a screen-shot of a page , so we are getting it into .jpg file.

So you can also do such customisation, but by default Pentaho is not provided this feature so far on components level.